Contenedores e imagenes docker borrados por accidente
Acabo de empezar en el mundo de Raspberry Pi 4 y Linux, 1 mes aproximadamente llevo. Y bueno, he empezado a trastear con docker y cuando ya tenia lo que quería listo, ocurrió el desastre.
El problema es que intentando borrar un servidor de minecraft, ejecuté
./cleanup

y cuando terminó, me había borrado los archivos de minecraft y ademas, los contenedores y las imágenes de docker.
Estoy mas perdido que un pulpo en un garaje y no se que puedo hacer. Alguien sabe si puedo reparar el desastre o tengo que empezar de cero otra vez??

Si no tienes ningun backup la única posibilidad que puedes aplicar es una busqueda a bajo nivel (forensics) en la tardjeta SD o almacenamiento que tengas.

Desgraciadamente no me ha dado tiempo a llegar a la parte de los backups. Lo de la busqueda a bajo nivel, no se que es. Gracias por responder.

Por si le sirve a alguien en la misma situación.
Afortunadamente he conseguido solucionarlo.
Buscando, he encontrado la carpeta /opt/docker/containers/ donde al parecer se guardan los contenedores.
Así que teniendo las carpetas de las aplicaciones donde están sus respectivos compose.yaml , he probado suerte y he ejecutado docker compose up -d en cada una de ellas.
Y voila! Las aplicaciones se han reinstalado conforme las tenia configuradas.

Es imposible recuperar archivos eliminados por usuarios con privilegios de superusuario. En este caso en concreto, debes empezar de cero esta vez y procura almacenar copias de seguridad. Mi consejo es que mires el archivo .bash_history ya que almacena comandos usados que suelen ser útiles para recordar los comandos que empleaste. Saludos.

Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Así haré. Alguna recomendación para hacer backups?

Para los backups, simplemente guardar una copia comprimida de cada version, simple pero efectivo.
